# android - accessing test application assets

Tags: android, xml, unit-testing, assets, suite

I've an XML file in the assets directory of my test application. I want to access this file from my suite method of the test class.

ie.,

public static TestSuite suite(){
    InputStream stream = // Some code which returns the asset
}

Any idea how I can do this? I tried with Resources.Resources.getSystem().getAssets() but no luck :-(. help please.

Thanx in adv,
Joseph

Answer (score 26):

I encountered the same problem with my test app. Unfortunately, it looks like getContext() in a test case class actually returns the context of the **application under test**. In order to get the context of the test application itself, you have to inherit from `InstrumentationTestCase` and then call `getInstrumentation().getContext()` to get the context of the test app.

Comment: Thx mikes, I didn't catch that before your post !

Comment: Can you provide a sample? getInstrumentation always returns null for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
final AssetManager assetMgr = context.getResources().getAssets();

final InputStream fileIn = assetMgr.open("my_file.txt", AssetManager.ACCESS_STREAMING);
```

We can use also this method [link text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#openXmlResourceParser%28java.lang.String%29) for xml-file.

Comment: Hi Damian, Thanx for the response.

Comment: Hi Damian, Thanx for the response. </br> How do we get the context object here? because the suite() is a static method, and the class do not inherit a context.

Comment: Try to use android test, where you have TestActivity. Evert Activity extends Context.