# How to mock database in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock database access (`OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`).

I just need a piece of information or some example how to achieve that.

I tried to create `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper` with `IsolatedContext`, but after running the code, Android just uses the standard context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7932055) you will see an answer for at least the latter part of your question: you need to extend *InstrumentationTestCase* rather than *AndroidTestCase* and call *getInstrumentation().getContext()* to get the context of the test application. However I have never used *OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper* and do not know whether it will help to mock a database. Actually, I am also searching for a way to mock.